# Android broadcast reciever returns null pointer exception with extended application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Ive created a simple broadcast receiver whose only purpose is when the phone boots up to start an alarmmanager method that I tucked away in an extended application file that handles application wide tasks like this, this works fine when I call it from an activity but, when I try to call it from a broadcast receiver it crashes and does not work, what Im thinking is perhaps I need to append the context to it in some way?

here is my code :

```
package com.testapp21.second.activities;

import com.testapp21.second.OTweetApplication;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class PhoneOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private OTweetApplication app;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        app.startChecks();

}
```

}

edit: startChecks then delegates off to a method in a helper file called startCheckshelper() here is what that block of code looks like this:

```
public void startCheckshelper(){
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(context,
              0, new Intent(context, CheckerService.class), 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
      long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

      // Schedule the alarm!
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                      firstTime, 60*1000, mAlarmSender);    
}
```

Comment: Is it crashing in startChecks()?  We'll need to know more info to help I think.

Comment: Ive added in the method it executes from the extended application

Answer (score 1):

You should always post your stack trace along with your question when asking about a crash in Android, but it looks like `app` is never initialized, yet you use it in `onReceive`.

Comment: whats an example of something I should initialize app to?

Comment: Assuming it's your extended application: `app = (OTweetApplication) getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized / assigned something to `app`, so it's null:

```
private OTweetApplication app;
```

And when you call it (`app.startChecks();`) you get the exception.

Comment: whats an example of something I should initialize app to?

Comment: To be honest - I don't know - I never worked with OTweetApplication before.